# Android in-app billing failed

Tags: android, billing

I've integrated the Google Android project named `Trivial Drive`:

**1.** Add this signed APK on my Google developer console in *beta-test*

**2.** I added 1 tester (my personal gmail `toto@gmail.com`)

**3.** I set "`free`" for application type

**4.** I added 1 integrated product; it's a subscription (named "`premium`") with a price, etc.

**5.** I push this signed APK (from `Android Studio`) to my mobile

**6.** I log with my `toto@gmail.com` on my mobile

**7.** I click on "`Upgrade my car`" in the main activity of this project, and the error message appears: *Impossible to buy this article* (Iab result: user canceled. response:-1005:User cancelled)

Do you have some explanations why this error appears? I configured my app like Free app, is it ok, even if I use some integrated products (like subscriptions, etc.) ?

For informations:

```
static final String SKU_PREMIUM = "premium";
```

Then :

```
public void onUpgradeAppButtonClicked(View arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Upgrade button clicked; launching purchase flow for upgrade.");
    setWaitScreen(true);
    String payload = "";

    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_PREMIUM, RC_REQUEST,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
}
```

On my Google Play console developer, I have this integrated product:

[image]

Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 0):

The message `user canceled. response:-1005:User cancelled` is displayed when an in-app purchase prompt/dialog is dismissed.

There is a possibility that after displaying the prompt to the user to make the in-app purchase you are doing something that is causing the dialog/pop-up for in-app purchase to dismiss, and hence the message. Make sure you are not doing something like that after displaying the in-app purchase dialog and waiting properly for the transaction to complete.

**Update after your question was updated with details:**

The sku looks like a managed product. It might have been already purchased. Make sure to consume it before letting the user purchase it again. In your case it can be purchased only once (logically - since it is an app upgrade to premium). So, you should check if it is already purchased and display appropriate message.

> **Managed In-app Products**
>
> Managed in-app products are items that have their ownership
>   information tracked and managed by Google Play. When a user purchases
>   a managed in-app item, Google Play stores the purchase information for
>   each item on a per-user basis. This enables you to later query Google
>   Play at any time to restore the state of the items a specific user has
>   purchased. This information is persistent on the Google Play servers
>   even if the user uninstalls the application or if they change devices.
>
> If you are using the Version 3 API, you can also consume managed items
>   within your application. You would typically implement consumption for
>   items that can be purchased multiple times (such as in-game currency,
>   fuel, or magic spells). Once purchased, a managed item cannot be
>   purchased again until you consume the item, by sending a consumption
>   request to Google Play. To learn more about in-app product
>   consumption, see [Consuming Items](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/google/play/billing/api.html#consume).

[Source](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/google/play/billing/api.html)

Comment: No, not at all. User canceled message appears when I press OK on Google billing popup.

Comment: then check if the item exists i.e. you are passing the correct sku.

Comment: I've completed my initial post with more details. thanks!

Comment: its a managed product, and might have been already purchased. Check updated answer.

Comment: Virus, I've checked this option but it's not that. I've created another SKU (add a new integrated product + change in code by "premium_new"), and the error is the same...

Comment: Is your app in production? Or still in alpha or beta?

Comment: in beta mode with 1 tester (me).

Comment: That could be it. Check testing permissions, if correctly configured.